# left join with group by returns no rows if table does not contains the specific id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

[image: skize]

I want to find out how many people rated a specific location. the problem is that my sql ONLY works if the hasVotedLocation table CONTAINS THE ID OF THE SPECIFIC LOCATION. Meaning if nobody voted the specific location i get zero rows.

My sql statement:

```
select count(*),l.idLoc from Location l
left join hasVotedLocation hvl
on hvl.idLoc=l.idLoc where l.idLoc=2
group by l.idLoc
```

[image: d]

For `idLoc=1` the query should return one row with `count(*)=3 and idLoc=1`

For `idLoc=2` the query should return one row with `count(*)=0 and idLoc=2`

For `idLoc=3` the query should return one row with `count(*)=1 and idLoc=3`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194971/discussion-on-question-by-jebemti-mater-left-join-with-group-by-returns-no-rows).

Answer (score 1):

In a GROUP BY query `COUNT(*)` returns the number of rows in the group. However when the condition in the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN doesn't match any row in the right table, the result will be one row with all columns from the right table filled with NULLs. That is still one row - not zero rows. Thus `COUNT(*)` will never return a value less than `1` in this query. But the result will also not be "zero rows" (as you stated in your question), as long as the condition in the WHERE clause matches any row in the left table.

To get the number of matches in the right table (the number of votes in your case), you should count the number of non NULL values from the right table. It is usually best to use the same column as in the ON clause (this way the engine can use the same index without a second lookup), which would be `COUNT(hvl.idLoc)`.

```
select count(hvl.idLoc), l.idLoc from Location l
left join hasVotedLocation hvl
on hvl.idLoc=l.idLoc where l.idLoc = ?
group by l.idLoc
```

However - If all you need is the number of votes for a specific `idLoc` value, you can just use a simple `COUNT(*)` query.

```
select count(*)
from hasVotedLocation 
where idLoc = ?
```

Note: In this query `COUNT(*)` will return `0`, if the WHERE condition doesn't match any row. This is because `SELECT *` would return zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `GROUP BY`:

```
select <someid> as idLoc, count(x)
from Location l left join
     hasVotedLocation hvl
     on hvl.idLoc = l.idLoc ;
```

This will always return one row.  The `count()` will be `0` if there are no matching rows.